# Swift disconnecting current GSM call

Tags: swift, callkit

What I'm trying to achieve is to disconnect a current GSM (not VoIP) call in some conditions. After a few days of research, I did end up here :) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

P.S to avoid my question to be too broad, I'd say that one of the methods I have tried is the following one. Anyway, it didn't success

```
let callController = CXCallController()
        let endCallAction = CXEndCallAction(call: currentCallID!)
        callController.request(
            CXTransaction(action: endCallAction),
            completion: { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    print("Success")
                }
            })
```

Comment: The method you are showing is to end the voip call. And I think you can only detect GSM call but can not end it.

Comment: I think you are very right. Looking for a workaround ...